# форма отправляется после загрузки страницы, а должна по клику на кнопку jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Форма отправляется после загрузки страницы, а должна по клику на кнопку "Отправить". Не могу понять в чем дело.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">РАСЧЕТ СТОИМОСТИ БАНКРОТСТВА</h4>
                    </div>
                    <form action="/calculator/submit.php" id="formForCalculator" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       //тело формы
                    </form>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="sendDataFromCalc" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

```js
$(function () {

   $('#formForCalculator').submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

    });

  $('#sendDataFromCalc').on('click', sendForm());

});


function sendForm() {
    var data = $('#formForCalculator').serializeArray();

    $.post('/calculator/submit.php', data, function(data, status) {
        if( status == 'success' ){
            alert('Данные успешно отправлены!');
        }else{
            alert('В процессе отправки произошла ошибка :(')
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: ошибка тут `on('click', sendForm())` ....должно быть `on('click', sendForm)`....во всяком случае если больше никуда не бросать свой взгляд)

Comment: Точно))) спасибо

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    // слушаем отправку формы
    $('#sendDataFromCalc').on('click', sendForm);


function sendForm(e) {
    // предотвращаем отправку формы
    e.preventDefault();
    // сериализация данных
    const data = $('#formForCalculator').serializeArray();
    // отправка данных
    $.post('/calculator/submit.php', data, function(data, status) {
        if( status == 'success' ){
            alert('Данные успешно отправлены!');
        }else{
            alert('В процессе отправки произошла ошибка :(')
        }
    })
}

});
```

Comment: А пояснений-то не будет?